# How to fix this Prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem since 1 hour and dont know where is the solution.
I made a prepared statements to insert elements from a form to the BDD and i dont know what is the problem, the problem from before the "exectute" because when i submit mi form i go to the "else".

my try catch look like :

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lucilledrx928', 'root', 'root');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

my prepared statement :

```
if (isset($_POST['titre'])) {
    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO news(user_id, titre, sous_titre, date, commentaire) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    if ($query->execute(array(
        strip_tags($_POST['user_id']),
        strip_tags($_POST['titre']),
        strip_tags($_POST['sous_titre']),
        strip_tags($_POST['date']),
        strip_tags($_POST['commentaire']),
    ))) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Votre news a été créer";
        header('location: add_news.php');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Erreur lors de l\'upload à la base de donnée';
    };
}
```

and my form :

```
<h2>Ajoutez une News</h2>
<?php
echo '<form style="min-width: 500px;" action="' . SITE_URL . '/admin/add_news.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
?>
    <p>Titre de l'article: <input type="text" name="titre"/></p>
    <p>Sous titre de l'article: <input type="text" name="sous_titre"/></p>
    <p>Les Models:
        <select name="user_id">
            <?php
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                echo '<option value="' . $user['id'] . '">' . $user['name'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Commentaire: <br/><textarea name="commentaire" rows="5" cols="45"></textarea></p>
    <p>Selection de Photo: <input type="text" id="member" name="member"
                                  placeholder="Choisir le nombre d'image"><br/>
        <a id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()" style="cursor: pointer">Valider le nombre de photo</a>
    <div id="addField"></div>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"></p>
    <p><input hidden value="<?php $date->format('Y-m-d') ?>" name="date"><br></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Envoyer"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message upon executing?

Comment: hello, how i have nothing, and nothing too when i trying to add the ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not what OP wants, but have you tried to construct it different. 
You could try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['titre'])&& !empty($_POST['titre']){

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO news (user_id, titre, sous_titre, date, commentaire) VALUES (:user_id, :titre, :sous_titre, :sous_titre, :date, :commentaire ) ");
    $query->bindParam(':user_id', $_POST['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':titre', $_POST['titre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':sous_titre', $_POST['sous_titre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':commentaire', $_POST['commentaire'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $res = $insertNews->execute();

if($res){
$_SESSION['msg'] = "Votre news a été créer";
        header('location: add_news.php');
} else {
$_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Erreur lors de l\'upload à la base de donnée';
}
}
```